# Python fabric quotes issue

Tags: python, quotes, fabric

Spent almost more than 30 mins of my time in trying all different possibly. Finally now I'm exhausted. Can someone please help me on this quote problem

```
def remote_shell_func_execute():
    with settings(host_string='user@XXX.yyy.com',warn_only=True):
            process = run("subprocess.Popen(\["/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh func2"\],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)")
            process.wait()
            for line in process.stdout.readlines():
                    print(line)
```

when run the fab, I get

```
fab remote_shell_func_execute
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Fabric-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/fabric/main.py",line 654, in main
docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Fabric-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/fabric/main.py",line 165, in load_fabfile
 imported = importer(os.path.splitext(fabfile)[0])
 File "/home/fabfile.py", line 18
process = run("subprocess.Popen(\["/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh        func2"\],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)")
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a single quoted string.

```
run('subprocess.Popen(\["/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh func2"\],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)')
```

Or escape the inner `"`.

```
run("subprocess.Popen(\[\"/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh func2\"\],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)")
```

Comment: first option didn't work. received the below `[root@null-000c293cc871.dv6594.homedepot.com] out: /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `\["/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh func2"\],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE'`

Second option contains this error `[root@null-000c293cc871.dv6594.homedepot.com] out: /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `\["/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh func2"\],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE'`

Comment: Do you have single quotes anywhere else in that command? If yes, then the second option would work.

Comment: @Sathy : That's an error from Bash. Your command is not quite right. Unfortunately, I don't know much Linux to help you more with this. The error is not coming from Python. Your Python script executes fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you escape quotes, the escape backslash must go directly before the quote character:

```
"[\"/..."
```

Alternatively, use single quotes for the string, this avoids the need for escaping at all:

```
'["/...'
```

Comment: thats a very quick reply. Let me try it.

Comment: is it problem with the quotes or with the square brackets ?

Comment: @Sathy Square brackets do not need to be escaped in strings - only the type of quote used to open/close the string needs to be. It's simply to tell Python that the string doesn't end there.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how can I get the below changed to `process = run('subprocess.Popen(["/root/test/shell_script_for_test.sh func2"],shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)')`

Comment: @Sathy There is no syntax issue there. You have another, separate problem.

Comment: My bash script looks pretty fine. It works well if I call the `subprocess` from command line. Only from `fab` it creates the `syntax issue`